# How to mathematically represent/describe the scenario?

Tags: probability

I want to estimate/compute the probability that a reasonable IT person will fail to patch a critical software leading to a hacker exploiting an IT system.

What kind of approach should I take in being able to calculate the probability in this scenario ? Any sample mathematical expressions or pointers appreciated.

What all information/varaiables parameters do I need to even make the calculations/estimations realistic ?

Comment: You will have to calculate the probability of a hack per year of operation, which over a number of years (using current insecure systems) will head remorselessly to 100%. Personally I think these are the wrong questions to ask. I would go for "When my system is hacked how do I limit the damage (stop the hacker grabbing everything), or alternatively, how do I feed the hacker with enough traceable fake information that it will hinder exploitation and help lead to their detection if they try to exploit the data?" Obviously such questions are off-topic here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use Poisson distribution: $$P(k \ events \ in \ interval ) = e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^k}{k!}$$

Where lambda $\lambda$ is the average number of events per interval.

So for example, let's say that a reasonable IT person makes an average of $1$ critical mistake per year ($1$ year is our interval). Let's also say that the chance of a critical mistake leading to a successful exploit from a hacker is $5 \%$ or $0.05$.

Summarizing the information we get that for example the chance of $k = 1$ successful exploits over a year, would be: $$P(1 \ exploit \ in \ a \ year ) = (0.05)e^{-1}\frac{1^1}{1!} = 0.01839... \ \approx 1.84 \%$$

So here you can change $k$ and $\lambda$ to be whatever you want, and the $0.05$ to be higher or lower depending on what your information is.